# How to count cells with data

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm getting values from range that I specified. But is there a way to count those values?
I'm using this method to get values from the sheets.

```
spreadsheetId :=""
range2 :=""
valueRenderOption := "FORMATTED_VALUE"

resp, err :=sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range2).ValueRenderOption(valueRenderOption).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `is there a way to count those values`?

Comment: Like, if I'm making range A1:C1, I need to know total number of values in this range.

Comment: As in, how many of those cells have data in them?

Comment: Yes! This is what I'm looking for

Comment: Can you provide an example response that the API gives you?

Comment: I'm trying to use len(resp.Values) but it gives me just 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- For `sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range2).ValueRenderOption(valueRenderOption).Do()`, when `A1:C1` gives to `range2`, the returned value is `{"majorDimension":"ROWS","range":"A1:C1","values":[["###","###","###"]]}`. In this case, `resp.Values` is 2 dimensional array. By this, `len(resp.Values)` returns `1`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When you want to retrieve the total number of cells from `sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range2).ValueRenderOption(valueRenderOption).Do()`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
resp, err := sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range2).ValueRenderOption(valueRenderOption).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
count := 0
for _, e := range resp.Values {
    count += len(e)
}
fmt.Println(count)
```

- In this case, when `A1:C1` is used for `range2`, `3` is returned.

#### Note:

- For example, when you want to retrieve the total number of cells which are not empty, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    resp, err := sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range2).ValueRenderOption(valueRenderOption).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    count := 0
    for _, e := range resp.Values {
        for _, f := range e {
            if f != "" {
                count++
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(count)
  ```
- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already been able to retrieve the values from Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: This method really solved this fo me! Thank you!

Comment: Oh, and to this also. Is there a method to show from wich cells I'm retrieving values? Like if I'm making range A1:C1, and then want to show all the cells so it would be like A1, B1, C1?

Comment: @WalterFox Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your comment of new question, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your new question, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: So I have a range of values A1:C1 for example. Is there a way to get list of names of all cells in this range. So for this example it would be A1, B1, C1

Comment: @WalterFox Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, I cannot still understand about your new question. I apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?

Comment: Thank you for your previous answers, it helped a lot! As for now I'm trying to find out if there's a column ID in Google Sheets API.